# Where can find WSDL file generated by gSOAP

Tags: soap, wsdl, gsoap

I received url of web service running on gSOAP/2.7 (deciding from HTTP headers). The problem is they didn't provide me with WSDL file. Anybody knows which default URL I should look for WSDL if service address is http://www.host.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the gsoap documentation at http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc18.10, I'd say that gsoap doesn't automatically provide a way to get the WSDL file.  It's a fairly low-level server, concentrating on being small and fast and leaving the fancy stuff for apache, etc.  Now it's possible your provider implemented a way to serve the WSDL, (it's pretty simple), but the access method would be dependent on them, and not standard.

Comment: I was expecting that but hoped I would be wrong because in the end I got WSDL file only after almost two month of asking for it :(

Comment: Well, it makes no sense to create a web service, then not provide a WSDL.  If you didn't want people to connect, why make it in the first place?  But I see a lot of crazy stuff in this business.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

you just need to create a header file that contain definitions.
http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc7.2.9

Answer (score 0):

Need to implement the fget function for soap: http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc19.10

Answer (score 0):

If you have the stub file you can generate WSDL file with following command:

```
soapcpp2.exe -i -C -Iimport gsoap.stub
```

You can get the soap2cpp2 tool with gsoap download.

Stub file is something like:

```
int ns1__executeCommand(char* command, char** result);
```

Answer (score -1):

It would be something like:

http://www.host.com/Something.asmx?WSDL

Comment: If you would knew how to answer this answer or at least read the question you would know that the service is running on gSOAP and that is C++ library not .Net as you suggest.